# Plugin for htmleditor not initialized

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I have a form panel with an htmleditor (`Ext.form.field.HtmlEditorView`).
The editor works fine, but I can't register plugins on it. The plugin from the code below never gets initialized.

Im using ExtJs 4.2

The plugin code:

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.wysiwyg.Filemanager', {
    alias: 'plugin.filemanager',

    init: function(cmp){
        console.log('init'); //Never gets initialized!
    }
});
```

And here is how I register the plugin on the htmleditor:

```
xtype: 'htmleditor',
plugins: [
    Ext.create('Ext.ux.wysiwyg.Filemanager')
]
```

So my question: how can I get a plugin on the htmleditor?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following sample code, it worked for me.

It is taken from [Extjs 4.2 docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.HtmlEditor), you can also test it there in the code editor / live preview.

Code:

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.wysiwyg.Filemanager', {
    alias: 'plugin.filemanager',

    init: function(cmp){
       alert( cmp.xtype ); // says "htmleditor"
    }
});

new Ext.panel.Panel({
    title: 'HTML Editor',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 550,
    height: 250,
    frame: true,
    layout: 'fit',
    items: {
        xtype: 'htmleditor',
        enableColors: false,
        enableAlignments: false,
        plugins: [
    Ext.create('Ext.ux.wysiwyg.Filemanager')
     ]
    }
});
```

Comment: You are adding a plugin on the panel. I want to add a plugin on the htmleditor. `cmp` should be the htmleditor object.

Comment: Yes sorry, now it works also when adding to the `htmleditor`. `cmp.xtype` in the `init()` says `htmleditor`. See edit.